# convert image data in to byte code using base64 encodein android

Tags: android, byte, arrays

i am developing one app i am using upload image in sdcard getting from uri of image ,
this convert in to byte array how can implemented i am new developer in android i am saving this image in byte array in database backend please forward some solution ....

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
            }
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)  
 {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
 {
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
 Cursor cur = PhotoImage.this.managedQuery(selectedImage, null, null, null, null);
 if(cur.moveToFirst())
 {
 long Length = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.SIZE));
 try{
 String Image=Base64.encodeBytes(selectedImage.getPath().getBytes());
 Log.v("check",Image);
 byte[] bytedata = new byte[(int) Length];
 FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(Img);
 fos.write(bytedata[0]);
 fos.close();
   }
 catch (Throwable th)
 {}
```

output is:

`12-30 13:00:24.619: VERBOSE/check(773): L2V4dGVybmFsL2ltYWdlcy9tZWRpYS8y`

this is the display output i think not converted in byte array please some solution ..

Comment: Is there a badge for the most unreadable question ?

Comment: what $%& are you doing here? Opening a stream and writing the first byte of an unitialized byte array?

Comment: i am asking how we can convert image data in to byte array using base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will convert image file into bytes:

```java
FileInputStream fin = c.openFileInput(path of file);
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[fin.available()];
fin.read(imageBytes);
```

put this in `try...catch()`

Try this and let me know if you are asking the same or some thing else.